# $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:m(E\cap(x-k,x+k))\geq k, \forall k>0\}$ is Lebesgue measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider a Lebesgue measurable set $E\subset\mathbb{R}$.  Prove that the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:m(E\cap(x-k,x+k))\geq k, \forall k>0\}$ is Lebesgue measurable.

I am just a bit confused on where to begin.  It looks like I can just apply the open set definition of measurability.  That is, there exists an open set $O$ with $E\subset O$ and $m(O-E)\leq\epsilon$.  But this would show that $E$ is measurable - and we already know that $E$ is.  But wouldn't the set in question just be an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$, which we know is measurable?  I feel like I am missing something quite simple....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $k$. Consider the function $$f_k(x)=m(E\cap(x-k,x+k)).$$ This function is continuous: using that $m(A)-m(B)=m(A\setminus B)-m(B\setminus A)$ for measurable $A,B$ and assuming $x<y$, 
$$
|f_k(y)-f_k(x)|=|m(E\cap(x-k, y-k))-m(E\cap[(x+k, y+k))|\leq2|y-x|.
$$
So $f_k$ is measurable, and 
$$
\{x\in\mathbb{R}:m(E\cap(x-k,x+k))\geq k, \forall k>0\}=\bigcap_kf_k^{-1}[k,\infty)
$$
is measurable.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  Thank you so much.